# best way to inject javascript into a iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web

I'm trying to inject a javascript into a iframe, but nothing works. I've already spent days with this issue, would be great if someone could give me some hints.

Example of subject:

The `example.html`:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://example.com/test.html" id="myFrame">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The `test.html`:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body background="./bg.jpg">
<p >Text </p>
<p >(<i>Something</i>)<br><img src="./img1.gif" align="left">Text</p>´
</body>
</html>
```

---

Desired Output from `test.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> src="myscript.js</script>
</head>
<body background="./bg.jpg">
<p >Text </p>
<p >(<i>Something</i>)<br><img src="./img1.gif" align="left">Text</p>´
</body>
</html>
```

---

---

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

The `example.html`:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
var rawframe = document.getElementById('myFrame');
var doc = rawframe.contentDocument;
if (!doc && rawframe.contentWindow) {
    doc = rawframe.contentWindow.document;
}
var script = doc.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "myscript.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://example.com/test.html" id="myFrame">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: If you are specifying a domain other than your own the the Same Origin Policy prevents you from accessing iframe contents.

Comment: No, I haven't access to the website.

Comment: Then you are locked out - by design.

Comment: A way around it, is to proxy a request to the url (with content you are trying to display) and output it from your domain. Now the iframe will be from your domain. However, this isn't good practice not to mention you may run into other security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe this is possible. I know I tried something along these lines before, but due to security reasons, browsers prevented it.

Comment: I had thoungt that this is the reason, why that don't work. But I was not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending script to the document of the parent page, not to the frame page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be achieved at all, but one problem I see is timing.
You would run the javascript code before the content of iframe is loaded, right?